# iPhone: Any way to create screenshots without lock button?

Tags: iphone

Sorry, not a programming question, but also important: Is there any way to create a screenshot of an iphone without using the combination home+lock button? JB-App? Something else?

Thx guys ;)

Greez, flo

Comment: Please don't say, "Sorry, I know this isn't a programming question, but...". It's one thing to not know the rules, but it's another to blindly ignore them. Consider asking on http://apple.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I'd like to migrate this to apple., but that's not one of the options under the vote to close / off topic list. But that's where this question belongs.

Comment: Sorry, i thought i could ask such stuff here, because i saw similar questions here ... But thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When the iPhone is connected to the computer, open the organiser in XCode, select your device and select the screenshots section, then press create new screenshot.